# Delete ALL rows that have a duplicate ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

There are plenty of posts on SO where a solution is given to take out rows that are in one way or form duplicate to other rows, leaving only 1.

What I am looking for is how I can delete all rows from my temp-table that do not have a unique ID:

```
ID    other_values
-----------------------------
 1    foo bar
 2    bar baz
 2    null
 2    something
 3    else
```

I don't care about the other values; once the `ID` is not unique, I want all rows out, the result being:

```
ID    other_values
-----------------------------
 1    foo bar
 3    else
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to remove rows with duplicated value while keeping one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495734/sql-to-remove-rows-with-duplicated-value-while-keeping-one)

Comment: @Smadger OP doesnt want keep one

Comment: @Smadger he asking to delete ALL not just leave one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
--delete all rows from my temp-table that do not have a unique ID
DELETE from MYTABLE
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: this would delete all duplicates and not leave 1. That is, if an ID has more than one, it'd remove the ID completely versus just removing all but one instance.

Comment: @scsimon That is exactly what OP want

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DELETE command in conjunction with a subquery to detect duplicates

```
DELETE
FROM mytable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM mytable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: this would delete all duplicates and not leave 1. That is, if an ID has more than one, it'd remove the ID completely versus just removing all but one instance

Comment: This is exacltly what the OP wants! See his example result set. All the rows with ID=2 have been removed.

Answer (score -1):

Use Cte to delete rows.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,Other_values
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id
            ) rownum
    FROM mytable
    )
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rownum > 1
```

Comment: This will leave one of the duplicated rows. And that isnt what OP want.